# Address a Multi Manager Swarm cluster

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I recently set up a swarm cluster consisting of 3 manager and 4 node instances. My test of the manager failover works great but I am wondering how to address the whole manager cluster instead of only a single address by a client to still be able to work if i.e. manager1 dies. I thought of something like

```
docker -H tcp://manager:9030 -H tcp://manager:9031 -H tcp://manager:9032 info
```

which doesn't work. Wasn't able to find any documentation on this either.